# Meaning of the expression

Tags: verilog

What does the following expression mean?

```
max-tick  =   (r-reg==2**N-1)  ?   l'bl  :  l'bO;
```

especially the ** operator, thanks.

Comment: It's ok, got the answer => exponentiation

Comment: Yup, 2 to the n-1 power.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
2**n-1 == (2**n)-1
```

and ** is exponent, 2 to the power of n, in other languages 2^n.